# Accessing a request scoped bean in a different thread (that handles websocket traffic)

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, websocket, stomp

I am having issues accessing a bean that is defined with a request centric scope in a thread that is not the request's thread.

My scenario is as follows:

1. Execution starts from a REST request coming from a client. In this request I define a bean that allows me to access data in a DB. The location of the DB depends on the user performing the request itself, hence why the  bean with which the db is accessed is bound to the request itself. I get the user details from the request's auth and use them to init the bean.
2. During the HTTP request the code may call to an external service over a websocket connection. The ws traffic is handled by different `StompFrameHandler` classes. When these handle traffic they do so on a dedicated thread, which is not the same as the initial http request (and rightfully so!).
3. Some of these `StompFrameHandler` classes need to access the DB relevant to the user in context for the current (REST) request.

At 3 is where I encounter the issue:

*No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.*

I understand what the error is telling me and the fact that due to how I have defined my bean (request scope bound) spring does not allow me to access it in other threads. However I still need to use that db accessing bean from the ws traffic handling thread.

Here is a simplified version of my code:

**The bean configuration:**

```
@Configuration
public class DbClientRequestScopeConfiguration {

    private DbClientFactoryI dbClientFactory;           
    private AuthenticationFacadeI authenticatedUserInfo;

    @Autowired
    public DbClientRequestScopeConfiguration(DbClientFactoryI dbClientFactory, AuthenticationFacadeI authenticatedUserInfo) {
        this.dbClientFactory = dbClientFactory;
        this.authenticatedUserInfo = authenticatedUserInfo;
    }

    @Bean
    @Scope(value = WebApplicationContext.SCOPE_REQUEST, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
    public DbClientI getDbClient() {        

        Authentication auth = authenticatedUserInfo.getAuthentication();        

        return dbClientFactory.getDbClient(auth.getDetails());              
    }
}
```

**The DataService using the bean** (this runs in the request's thread)

```
@Service
public class DataService {

    private DbClientI dbClient;     

    @Autowired
    public DataService(DbClientI dbClient) {

        this.dbClient = dbClient;       
    }

    ...
}
```

**The frame handler working with the WS traffic** Note that this in not initialised by Spring's context, instead it is manually initialised by a class running in the request's thread, which gives it the instance of the @DataService coming from the Context.

```
public class SaveDataFrameHandler implements StompFrameHandler{

    private DataService dataService;

    public SaveDataFrameHandler(DataService dataService) {      
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    @Override
    public Type getPayloadType(StompHeaders headers) {
        return JsonNode.class;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleFrame(StompHeaders headers, Object payload) {
        // This method will be called on a separate thread
        JsonNode jsonPayload = (JsonNode) payload;
        dataService.saveRecord(jsonPayload);            
    }
}
```

I am looking for suggestions on how I could actually use that bean in my ws thread or how to rearchitect the solution so that I do not run into this problem.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

I have managed to get around the problem for now even though I am not 100% happy with the solution. To avoid repetition, I posted my current solution in a new question, since I am facing a different issue now still related to this code: 
[Proxied prototype bean is created every time a method is invoked from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53667240/proxied-prototype-bean-is-created-every-time-a-method-is-invoked-from-it)

Comment: Please provide the relevant part of your code. Add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) including proper example input/output data.

Comment: Hi, sure thing! I just edited my post to add the code. Cheers.