# Proxied prototype bean is created every time a method is invoked from it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am having an issue accessing a Request scoped bean from a websockets callback thread (different thread than the one managing the original HTTP request - hence the issue). You can read more about it here: 
[Accessing a request scoped bean in a different thread (that handles websocket traffic)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444273/accessing-a-request-scoped-bean-in-a-different-thread-that-handles-websocket-tr)

I have since, managed to get around the problem (even though I am not 100% happy with the solution) but I am seeing a behaviour I do not understand.

My current solution is as follows: 
I have changed the Bean from request scope to prototype scope:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "prototype", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public DbClientI getDbClient() throws StrykeDomainException {       
   DbClientI dbClient = requestContextHolder.getAttribute("dbClientReq", DbClientI.class);      
   if (dbClient != null) {
       logger.info("Retrieved DbClient proxy instance: {}", dbClient.hashCode());
   }    
   return dbClient;
}
```

I am creating and destroying the instance behind the Bean in a dedicated Interceptor (HandlerInterceptorAdapter) and storing it in the RequestContextHolder, so that it can be retrieved by my Bean configuration (above).

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler) {

    boolean shouldProceedInterceptorChain = true;

    if (authenticatedUserInfo.isUserAuthenticated()) {

        try {
            DbClientI dbClient = dbCliFactory.createDbClientForCurrentRequest();
            requestContextHolder.setAttribute("dbClientReq", dbClient, true);                           
            dbClient.connect();     

        } catch (Exception e) {
            shouldProceedInterceptorChain = false;              
        }                           
    }

    return shouldProceedInterceptorChain;
}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Object handler, final Exception ex) {

    //Note: we must use this method to disconnect instead of "postHandle", because postHandle will not run in case of an exception 
    if (authenticatedUserInfo.isUserAuthenticated()) {          
        DbClientI dbClient = appContext.getBean(DbClientI.class);            
        if (dbClient != null && dbClient.isConnected()) {
            dbClient.disconnect();                
            dbClient = null;
        }
    }
}
```

The solution works, but the method getDbClient() is called every time the dbClient Bean is accessed in the code! Calling a method off the dbClient bean from within another bean causes the getDbClient() method to be called.
My understanding is that the getDbClient() method should only get called each time it is injected into another bean, for example when injecting it in the constructor of another bean. This is what the Spring docs say:

> The non-singleton, prototype scope of bean deployment results in the
>   creation of a new bean instance every time a request for that specific
>   bean is made (that is, it is injected into another bean or it is
>   requested via a programmatic getBean() method call on the container)
>   https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html#beans-factory-scopes-prototype

Functionality-wise this is fine because underneath there is always the same instance of DbClient (the one created by the interceptor), but the fact that the method getDbClient() is called every time the bean is used is surely impacting performance.

How can I change my code so that getDbClient() is only called when the bean is supplied to another bean and not every time it is used?
Thanks.

Comment: There is no scope with desired behavior.

Comment: @talex could you please elaborate? Are you saying that the default behaviour of a prototype scoped bean is to be created every time it is used? That is not what the docs say...

Comment: It is called when it's accessed probably because it's in @Lazy mode if you put @Lazy(false) on the bean you should see the invocation on the injection

Comment: I'm sure that "every time a request for that specific bean is made" mean that every time a request for that specific bean is made (like you do `appContext.getBean(DbClientI.class)`) you get new bean instance

Comment: @gaber84 I annotated the getDbClient() method with @Lazy(false) but it made no difference.

Comment: @talex maybe I did not explain it clearly enough. Unfortunately, what happens is not that a new bean is supplied to me every time it is injected into another bean or whenever calling appContext.getBean(DbClientI.class). That would be what I want. However, what I am seeing is that, every time the instance of DbClient is used inside another bean (eg: calling a method on it: dbClient.connect(), dbClient.getRecordById(), etc.) the getDbClient() method in my Configuration class is called.

Comment: Yes. That is how it works. It create new instance every time it accessed. `appContext.getBean` in fact return proxy.

Comment: @talex only if the Bean is marked to use a proxy (like in my example). If prototype scope is used without a proxy, a new instance is only created at the time of injection or getBean(), not at the time of using the bean itself. See my answer below... thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the insight from the comments and doing a bit more testing on my end I realised that the key of my misunderstanding lied on the usage of the proxy.

Indeed, as the Spring docs say, when using a Prototype scope a new instance will only get created every time the bean is injected or ApplicationContext.getBean() is called. A new instance will NOT get created just by simply accessing the bean, for example by calling a method on it.

However, if the same bean is also decorated with the proxy property, what gets created on injection is a proxy and not an actual instance of the class. This results in Spring calling the "configuration method" to retrieve the actual underlying instance (in my case the getDbClient method) every time the bean is accessed (eg: calling a method on it).

Note that the above is true for "proxyed" prototype beans. For "proxyed" request scoped beans, a single call to get the actual instance will be performed at the start of the request. Subsequent use of the bean will not trigger a call to retrieve a new instance of the bean.